# Angularjs variable does not update inside view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that returns a JSON onbject on search results, I use ng-repeat to list through them. I use a button with a ng-click event tied to the ID of that particular object.

```
<div ng-controller="Gid"><button ng-click="getGid(val['gid'])">Test</button></div>
```

This div is inside a larger controller that is executing the ng-repeat. Not sure if it makes a difference, but I doubt it does.

Then inside the 'Gid' controller I have the 'getGid()' function that takes the id as an argument.

```
.controller('Gid', function($scope, $http, $location){

$scope.getGid = function(id){

    $http({

        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/places/search_places",
        method: "POST",
        data: null

    }).then(function(response){

          // currently I'm just sending null to test this so I know the    
         // response comes back bad

    }).catch(function(response){


        $scope.gid = id;
        console.log($scope.gid); // I can see the correct id in console
        $location.path('/view1')

    })

}

})
```

After this, I would assume all should be well. I can see in the console that the correct ID is indeed showing up. However, when the path changes to view1

```
<div ng-controller="Gid">
1 - {{ gid }}
</div>
```

The gid variable stays empty. I have tried setting it to null to start at the top of the controller, and that made no difference. I tried it without the HTTP call, that made no difference. But I need that call anyway for this function to work down the line.

So what gives? Why is my variable not getting updated on the view side when I can clearly see it is updated in the console.

Comment: Seems like you have multiple instances of the same controller. They each have their own scope. You need a service for both of those instances to share data

Comment: Ah, yeah I guess that makes sense. It just seems like such overkill to design a service for this. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Not recommended but if you just want to test it....add the `gid` to `$rootScope`. All scopes inherit from `$rootScope`

Comment: Thanks I ended up just writing a quick little service and it's fine. It was just my overlook because the operation is so simple I figured it would be done all in one.